# How to show only from email address in using HTML mailto?

Tags: html, email

Testing my HTML mailto-generated email, I get the following:

> From: Sender Name
>
> To: mydomain@domain.com

How do I convert it to:

> From: senderdomain@domain.com
>
> To: mydomain@domain.com

I plan on using HTML's mailto link only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mailto:` protocol does not have anything to do with the "From" address. That is up to the mail client.

Comment: Thank you so much @David. There's nothing I can do then.